# Nested XML to CSV, generic code

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

This is a tough one.

I have to deal with some XML files we've got from our suppliers. The files contain the products and the variants (color, size, and such). Some of the suppliers send us plain XMLs, containing one root node per variant, having the product name repeated on every row, other suppliers send us nested XMLs, containing the product as root, variants as children nodes.

I have searched the site before asking this question, all the answers I found start with the assumption the XML structure is known.

In my case, it's not. Tomorrow I can get files from a new supplier, with a different structure/different column names.

My goal is to convert the nested xml into a plain xml (i.e. having only root nodes, and repeat the product name for all the new created rows).

Is this even possible? Any idea?

Comment: Could you post some sample source and your idea how result should look like? I think the solution is possible, but it is not 100% clear what you are asking for.

Comment: Simple solution :  string xml = File.ReadAllText("filename");
            string modifiedXml = string.Format("<root>{0}</root>", xml);